# Перевод из Pascal в Python

Tags: python, pascal, перевод

Пытался перевести из паскаля в питон:

```
var a: array[1..100] of integer;
i, k: integer;
begin
  for i:= 1 to 100 do
    if i*2 >= 65 then
      a[i]:= 1
    else 
      a[i]:= 0;
    for k:= 1 to 100 do
    for i:= 1 to 100 do
      if a[i] = 0 then
        if (a[i+1] > 0) and (a[i*2] > 0) then
          a[i]:= max(a[i+1], a[i*2])*-1
        else 
          if (a[i+1] < 0) or (a[i*2] < 0) then
            a[i]:= min(a[i+1], a[i*2])*-1+1;
       for i:= 1 to 64 do
         if a[i] = 1 then
           print(i);     
end.
```

Получилось так:

```
a = [1, 101]
i = int()
j = int()
for i in range(1, 101):
    if i*2 >= 65:
        a[i] = 1
    else:
        a[i] = 0
    for k in range(1, 101):
        for i in range(1, 101):
            if a[i] == 0:
                if (a[i+1] > 0) and (a[i*2] > 0):
                    a[i] = max(a[i+1], a[i*2])*-1
                elif (a[i+1] < 0) or (a[i*2] < 0):
                    a[i] = min(a[i+1], a[i*2])*-1+1
for i in range(1, 65):
    if a[i] == 1:
        print(i)
```

В итоге пишет ошибку:

```
if (a[i+1] > 0) and (a[i*2] > 0):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Скажите пожалуйста, что не так сделал?

Comment: ошибка в первой строке напишите `*a, = range(1,101)`

Comment: a[i] = 0
TypeError: 'range' object does not support item assignment

Comment: пишите со звездочкой и запятой

Comment: из того, что сразу видно. `a = [0] * 100` - создаст список из 100 элементов. далее, в питоне индексы в списках начинаются с нуля.

Comment: можно так написать `a = list(range(1,101))`

Comment: Работает, но в конце, где:
for i in range(1, 65):
    if a[i] == 1:
        print(i)
если мы поставим a[i] == 2, либо -1 или -2, то ничего происходить не будет

Comment: напишите пожалуйста ожидаемый результат

Comment: В конце, при a[i] == -1 ответ должен быть таким:
32
При a[i] == 2:
16
31
При a[i] == -2:
30

Comment: почему индекс может доходить до 200? `a[i*2]`

Comment: Какой результат вы получаете на паскале?

Comment: программа на паскале ошибку выдает

Comment: На паскале:
В конце, при a[i] == -1 ответ должен быть таким:
32 
При a[i] == 2: 16 31
 При a[i] == -2: 
30